# when creating partition it shows error

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `cloud_ip_cost_details1` (

  `ipcost_details_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `server_entry_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `ip_address` BLOB,

  `project_name` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,

  `project_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `group_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `division_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,

  `cost` BLOB,

  `period` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,

  `updated_by` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,

  `temp_id` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ipcost_details_id`)

)

PARTITION BY LIST(period)(


    PARTITION Jan2017 VALUES IN ('Jan-2017')
);
```

> Error Code : 1697
>
> VALUES value for partition 'Jan2017' must have type INT

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  What don't you understand?

Comment: it is possible to create with char in partition. when PARTITION Jan2017 VALUES IN (2017) it will accept instead of 2017 to 'Jan-2017' not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(period) (
    PARTITION Jan2017 VALUES IN('Jan-2017')
);
```

or this:

```
 PARTITION BY RANGE (period)
    ( PARTITION Jan2017 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2012-07-01')) 
 );
```

documentation:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-columns-list.html

Answer (score 1):

We need to make a couple of changes:

- We need to use `PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS` phrase instead of `PARTITION BY COLUMNS`
- Partitioned column needs to be a part of the table keys (documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html)), so we need to add `period` to `primary key`.

Below should work:

```
CREATE TABLE `cloud_ip_cost_details1` (

  `ipcost_details_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `server_entry_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` BLOB,
  `project_name` VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `project_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `division_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cost` BLOB,
  `period` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_by` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `temp_id` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`ipcost_details_id`, `period`)

)

PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(period)(
    PARTITION Jan2017 VALUES IN ('Jan-2017')
);
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33f6a4/1/0)**.

Comment: when add LIST Columns it shows error. Error Code : 1503
A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Comment: @sridhard I have updated my answer. Can you try it again?